# Nginx - Configuration VirtualHost for DreamVids

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to test DreamVids (https://github.com/DreamVids/DreamVids on branch v2) on my server with Nginx and PHP-FPM.
But i have a problem when i try to access it, it downloads a file.

My configuration is :

```
    server {
          server_name mydomain.fr;

          root /home/dreamvids/DreamVids;
          index index.html index.htm index.php;

          error_page 404 index.php;
          autoindex off;

          location / {
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
                if (!-e $request_filename){
                       rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 break;
                }
          }

          location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                include fastcgi_params;
          }
    }
```

Thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /home/dreamvids/DreamVids;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
            if (!-e $request_filename){
                   rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 break;
            }
      }
            location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but listen 80 is already on .conf and the result is the same

Comment: By default my nginx listen 80. With your conf the result is the same.